# Cannot browse to sub-domain

Tags: dns, firewall, browser

Using Firefox on Ubuntu18.04, and I somehow must have messed up some internal tables, for I'm unable to reach a sub-domain. I tried with Chromium, to no avail (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN). The message in Firefox: "We can’t connect to the server at domino-ideas.hcltechsw.com."

On a Windows VM everything works (on the same Ubuntu machine), so I know both the main and the sub domains are active.

Main: https://hcltechsw.com
Sub: https://domino-ideas.hcltechsw.com

What did I do wrong, and how to fix this?

Comment: Your only info is links to your Companies Web Page? I don't think you provided enough info to help.

Comment: It is not my company. I'll add what FF tells me to the question.

Comment: Weird, I can Browse both links fine......

Comment: That's what I impiled: both sites work, yet not here on my Ubuntu system. Somehow a firewall, the dns or something else blocks the sub-domain. I cannot even ping the sub-domain.

Comment: Nothing to do with security AFAIK. I corrected http in https in the question (typo, sorry). I have one other url with a sub-domain and it works correctly. So does bugs.launchpad.net, it works here. Not domino-ideas.hcltechsw.com though.

Comment: There should be some log somewhere that can provide a reason it's not working. Sry, Just a Novice User. `journalctl -qb /usr/bin/firefox`

Comment: Nothing to do with site config, server config, etc.  This isn't even an Ubuntu issue necessarily, this is a DNS issue and a misconfiguration at the domain's DNS level with the CNAME being wrong (and not RFC compliant).  (See my answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CNAME record for the subdomain at the DNS level is wrong and incorrect.  The CNAME currently returns as: `https://domino.ideas.aha.io` which is NOT a valid CNAME entry. (see the [RFC1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#page-13) detailing hostnames, [RFC2219](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2219) detailing the use of DNS aliases which are what CNAMEs are, and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) and [DNSSimple](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/cname-record/)'s pages on CNAME syntax and details on CNAME records)

The CNAME record is supposed to be the ***domain only*** - not a URL, not an IP address, no scheme to define connection patterns - JUST the domain that this is being an 'alias' to for IP resolution.

Web browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, Edge / Internet Explorer, Opera, etc. all rely on the CNAME entries actually being ***DNS compliant***, and this DNS entry is not.

(While modern `dig` and such are capable of doing the translations of this to the proper CNAME entry, CNAMEs are ***NOT*** HTTP/HTTPS redirects and ***MUST*** be compliant with the rules for CNAMEs, and browsers are not robust enough to actually process these kinds of mistakes in DNS record entries)

Wherever the DNS for your domain is hosted, you need to update your DNS to actually have the CNAME be `domino.ideas.aha.io` and not the URL you're targeting.

---

Below is the verbose `dig @8.8.8.8 domino-ideas.hcltechsw.com.` lookup results, showing the CNAME and such.  Note that `dig` is an ISC tool that is used to do DNS lookups and return DNS results, but most browsers will use the system's resolver functions which may not be as 'flexible' as `dig` is for resolving things.

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 domino-ideas.hcltechsw.com.

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.9-Ubuntu <<>> @8.8.8.8 domino-ideas.hcltechsw.com.
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9549
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;domino-ideas.hcltechsw.com.    IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
domino-ideas.hcltechsw.com. 299 IN  CNAME   https://domino.ideas.aha.io.
https://domino.ideas.aha.io. 3599 IN    A   35.171.201.123

;; Query time: 61 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Oct 28 10:29:26 EDT 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 112
```

Comment: Ah... Would that be something the owner of the website has to change? Or is it on my system? Can you explain why it works on Windows10 using FF70.0, but not on Ubuntu18 with FF70.0?

Comment: @D.Bugger as I said, it's down to the system resolver to handle the resolution properly, some browsers have their own resolver but most don't. The resolver in 18.04+ by default is `systemd-resolved` which is going to be RFC-strict. Windows is probably taking after `dig` and learning how to convert the incorrect URL in the CNAME to a domain properly, but Ubuntu likely isn't, which is fine because the CNAME is **just plain wrong** the way it's configured. And yes, the owner of the domain has to update Amazon's DNS to properly be the right CNAME entry, and not a URL in the CNAME entry.

Comment: So it's definitely not on my end? Nice :-) I'll send the site owner to get their act together. Thanks!

Comment: @D.Bugger 95% chance it's on the site owner's end, not yours.  Not all DNS servers and resolvers are as nice as Google's DNS resolvers and most will NOT convert 'invalid' DNS records to 'usable' like my `dig` output shows - once the site owner fixes the CNAME to be RFC compliant chances are the issue will 'resolve itself' for the most part.